# adjectives and past participles used as nouns

Tags: nouns, adjectives, determiners

In general, 
'the + adjective' and 'the + past participle' could be used instead of a plural noun phrase.

> The good die young.
>
> The damned will bury the dead.

I think in certain cases that structure could be used instead of a singular noun.

> 'The Good, The Bad and the Ugly'
>
> I was not the hunter but the hunted. (the hunted one)

Also, the structure is sometimes used with a possessive or an indefinite article instead of 'the'.

> An accused
>
> A condemned
>
> God's chosen

Three questions:

1. Is this structure is ever used for non-humans?
2. Is it ever used for non-living things?
3. Is it ever used with a determiner other than 'the' when we don't have a past participle, but an adjective?

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, it is used for non-humans, as in "the wolves prey upon the deer, watching for the young and the wounded".
2. It can be used for non-living things: "He collected paintings, preferring the dour and the gilt-framed."
3. I think not, as it would be impossible to tell the plural from the singular in this situation.

Comment: That's right: adjectives never inflect for number, not even under ad hoc nominalization. "We serve anyone, both the fair and the foul." However, once it gains an independent sense as a substantive, then it inflects. Consider "the good, the bad, and the ugly"; those don't become plural just because one has several of each. Such things as *goods* exist but mean something else. *Uglies* and *bads*, not so much.